# What's The Proper Way To Combine Observable Data In Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I do not have a lot of experience with RxJS and Async data.  I have been nesting subscriptions and it doesn't feel right.  I am wonder what is the proper way to combine or use multiple data points, such as getting a user profile and their posts.  Here is what I have currently:

```
  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage, private db: AngularFirestore, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    // Get profile
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      const profileName = params.get('id');
      const username = db.doc<any>('usernames/' + profileName).valueChanges();
      username.subscribe(val => {
        this.user = db.doc<User>('users/' + val.user).valueChanges();
        this.user.subscribe(val => {
          const userPosts = this.db.collection<Post>('posts', ref => ref.where('user', '==', val.uid)).snapshotChanges();
          this.posts = userPosts.pipe(map(actions => actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
            const mediaUrl = this.storage.ref('post/m/' + data.mediaM).getDownloadURL();
            const userData: Observable<User> = db.doc<User>('users/' + data.user).valueChanges();

            return {mediaUrl, userData, ...data}
          })))
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: not clear what you need or what is not working

Comment: @Dalorzo It's not that it doesn't work; I don't like that subscriptions are nested inside subscriptions. I am looking for a better or proper solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use switchMap to pipe the result from one observable into another so you don't need to nest subscriptions.

```
this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  map(params => params.get('id')),
  switchMap(profileName => db.doc<any>('usernames/' + profileName).valueChanges()),
  switchMap(val => db.doc<User>('users/' + val.user).valueChanges()),
  switchMap(val => this.db.collection<Post>('posts', ref => ref.where('user', '==', val.uid)).snapshotChanges())
).subscribe(val => {});
```

Comment: This is a clean solution.  It allows me to use switch map to get the profile data and then create a separate variable for posts.  Keeping data separated and reusable is a plus.